# Why is MATLAB used so much in industry when there's other software that can do a better job?

Tags: matlab

All the classes I'm taking require the projects to be done in MATLAB when there are times that C++ would be much better to use. One time the professor took three hours to find a transfer function when it would have taken two minutes tops in Maple or Mathematica. I've heard about people using Python but I've never really looked into it.

Comment: When your only tool is a hammer, every problem look like a nail.

Comment: If your professor took three hours to find a transfer function, you professor is inept: https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=matlab+transfer+function The first link is the matlab documentation for transfer functions.

Comment: Matlab is a *discrete* (e.g. approximate) solver; Maple and Mathematica are *symbolic* (e.g. exact) solvers. They are different tools for different purposes.

Comment: This is a statement disguised as a question. Vote to close.

Answer (score 6):

Matlab is largely equal to Mathematical is largely equal to Maple. Just because **you** are more familiar with one does not make it "better".

The reason Matlab/Mathematica/Maple are popular are because they are much, **much** easier to get started in then C++/most programming languages. They come ready-to-go with everything you need to draw graphs, do differential calculus, whatever.
Furthermore, there is a **help system**.

All this makes them *dramatically* more appealing to people who are *not* computer science majors (e.g. mathematicians, biologists, physicists, etc...).

As for your professor taking two hours to find a transfer function.... What? The **first** google search result for "[Matlab transfer function](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=matlab%20transfer%20function)" is the mathworks documentation page on the [matlab transfer function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html).

---

As an aside, python is making significant inroads on the mathematical computing world, primarily because of it's philosophy of **[batteries included](http://www.python.org/about/)**. While the default plain python install isn't particularly targeted and scientific computing, there are [specific distros](https://www.enthought.com/products/epd/free/) that provide a environment similar to matlab straight from a single install.

Python also has the benefit of being much more powerful and flexible the purpose-specific languages like Matlab/Mathematica/Maple. Python started out as a general language, matlab started out as being a language for math students, and bolted on general purpose tools later on.